# why are my returns values adding up when i have multiple if statements? C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int compare (int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    if (a > b){return 1;}
    else if (a < b) {return -1;}
    else if (a == b){   if (c > d){return 1;}
                        else if (c < d) {return -1;}
                        else if (c == d) {return 0;}}
}
int main(void) {
int r = compare(11, 2, 2, 1);
printf("r: %d\n");}
```

when I print the function result I get a result of 2 or 4 I don't know what I'm doing incorrectly. this should be simply 1, -1 or 0

Comment: For future question please always provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows how you call your function. Together with input, output and expected output.

Comment: Whatever you are doing wrong is happening when you call `func`. Show that code.

Comment: Such if-else-if-else-if-else-if sequences should end in an unconditional else to make sure you don't miss a case.

Comment: had a typo with a == b, so basically im trying to check if a number is higher or lower or equal to the other number. if the first pair of numbers are equal it will go to the next pair but if the first pair isnt equal it wont go to the next pair.

Comment: You should make `else if(a==b)`  and unconditional `else`. Same for the nested `else if (c==d)`. And you should show us the calling code.

Comment: Doesn't your compiler warn you that you do not pass any value to `printf("r: %d\n");`? Turn up warning level.

Comment: Post the actual code that compiles, as a [mcve].

Comment: thanks for the advice, its giving me warnings "control reaches end of non void function"

Comment: The tests in `else if (a == b)` and in `else if (c == d)` are superbly.  You could simply write `else`.  Or, in place of `else if (a == b)`, you could usefully write `else if (c > d)` and avoid a level of indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf("r: %d\n");` fails to pass any value for `printf` to print. It should be `printf("r: %d\n", r);`.

Enable warnings in your compiler and elevate warnings to errors.  With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`.